# xargs and command substition issues

Tags: linux, shell, sh, jq, xargs

So, i have a horrifying oneliner, that gets a json value extracts data from it using jq and then iterates over the data with xargs. In the end it should produces some xml

```sh
legendary list-installed --json | jq '.[].title' | sed s/"\""/""/g | xargs -n1 -p -d "\n" -I {} echo '<button onclick="'$(legendary list-installed --json | jq 'map(if .title == "'{}'" then .app_name elif .title == "_" then "_" else "_" end)')'">'{}'</button>'
```

First of all, i didn't use the `-r` flag with jq because i thought the issue might be comming from it.

The expected output should be something like this:

```xml
<button onclick=app name e.g. Coley> The Escapist 2 </button>
```

So far that works (except for the app name part, as thats where it begins to get weird)

Because i hardly can debug with jq inside the command substition, i wanted to test what xargs gets passed into stdin via another command substition. I changed the part between the two button elements `{}` to `$(echo {})`, which still works. But by accident i piped it into `wc -w`, which outputs ONE if the content of the {} is actually TWO!
[image]

```
❯ ./test.sh
<layout>
echo 'button onclick="[' '"_",' '"_",' '"_"' ']">Ape Out</button>' ?...^C⏎                                                                                                                                           
> cat test.sh
...'$(echo {})'</button>'
```

If i just echo the content of {} it returns this (i know that thats a useless echo, its just for consistency):
[image: second image]
When i count the words inside of my shell, and not inside of xargs

```
legendary list-installed --json | jq '.[].title' | head -n 1 | sed s/"\""/""/g | wc -w
```

it does return two.

Output of running with `set -x`

```
❯ ./test.sh
+ echo '<layout>'
<layout>
+ legendary list-installed --json
+ jq '.[].title'
+ sed 's/"//g'
++ legendary list-installed --json
++ jq 'map(if .title == "{}" then .app_name elif .title == "_" then "_" else "_" end)'
++ echo '{}'
++ tee lolsu,txt
+ xargs -n1 -p -d '\n' -I '{}' echo 'button onclick="[' '"_",' '"_",' '"_"' ']">{}</button>'
echo 'button onclick="[' '"_",' '"_",' '"_"' ']">Ape Out</button>' ?...
```

Seems like its not being substituted correctly... New problem is how i would make it replace the {} with the real one, inside of the substition.

TLDR:
counting the value of xargs returns one, while the piped input should be two words (as i am iterating over line and not word)
When running in shell it returns two (without using xargs, obv)

Comment: `$(echo {})` won't work. `{}` has to be an argument to `xargs`, not in a subshell. That's just echoing a literal `{}`

Comment: @Barmar acutally, it does work! seems like xargs implemented the $() thing on its own. Demonstration: [image](https://i.imgur.com/hXjHlzX.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually writing. But if you just put `$(echo {})` into the command line, that's essentially the same as just putting `{}` into the command line, since `$(...)` is replaced with the output of `...`

Comment: E.g. do `echo $(echo {})`

Comment: Yes i know that, but the weird thing is, when i pipe it into `wc -w` it says it's only one word, while its clearly 2 https://i.imgur.com/M50ThTY.png

Comment: Please show the command line in the question. It's hard to tell what's going on from a description.

Comment: Done - 11 more characters to go

Comment: Please use text, not an image. I can't read that.

Comment: Added some text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
$(echo {} | wc -w)`
```

The input to the `wc -w` command is the string `{}`. That's one word, so the result is `1`, and that gets substituted in place of `$(echo {} | wc -w)`. It's *not* substituting anything from `xargs` there, because command substitutions are executed first and the results substituted into the command line.

So the argument that `xargs` receives contains this `1` already substituted.

Comment: but why does the echo then work inside of the substition?

Comment: It's echoing the literal string `{}`. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: See the newly added text... It's echoing the real and only content of the {}, which is Ape Out

Comment: When you just have `$(echo {})` is the same as just writing `{}`. `xargs` then receives that as an argument, and replaces it with the current element of the iteration.

Comment: The problem was when you used `$(echo {} | wc -w)`. That substitutes the output of `wc -w` into the `xargs` command, it doesn't replace `{}` with the iteration element.

Comment: I suggest you run your script with `set -x` so you can see the order of substitutions.

Comment: Umm thats probably also whats happening in the first substition, which is the thing why i am asking this question in the first place. Do you know how i can fix that, to not be {} but instead the content?? Oh i didn't see the set -x part. i'll try that and report back

Comment: I suggest you write a shell script that receives the text as an argument and formats it as you want, and call that script with `xargs`. Doing it all in a one-liner will drive you crazy.

Comment: Okay i put it in a different shell script, and i can call it. but i can't add the content of {} to the args, as it is the same issue, as i had before. Its sending a literal {}...

Comment: I just went with a traditional for loop, instead of xargs. Works like a charm now.